# manual layout of a custom UITableViewCell for this approach?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Background - I have a custom UITableViewCell layout. Each cell will have a number of UILabels with a variable number of rows of UILabels.  For the sake of argument conside 3 columns of UILabels (different widths), and a variable number of rows depending on the data.

To best allow for content view size changes (e.g. edit mode, change in orientation etc) I was going to manually layout each of the UILabels in the cell in the "layoutSubviews" method, effectively setting up their exact positions.  I thought this way they will be laid out appropriately for events such as EDIT mode, orientation change etc.

Question - I'm wondering whether from a performance point this is the best approach?  Or should I be looking at somehow predefine the UILabel rows, one predefined set for portrait mode and another set for landscape mode?  (not exactly sure of how this would be done, but I'm trying to describe an approach where the layout would not have to be re-calculated when orientation changes etc)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

suggestion by RickMaddy elsewhere was good:

"Why have a variable number of rows of labels in a single table row? Have one row of labels per table row. Then the problem is easier and performance won't be an issue."